# Change invalid status of locale reference from directive

Tags: angular

I have custom select2 directive.

```
<select select2 name="activityId" #activity="ngModel" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="company.activityId" required>
      <option [value]=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of lookup.activities;" [value]="item.id">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Into select tag a i have local reference variable "#activity", after choosing value in select2 a activity.invalid not updating from true to false.

How can i update it custom from directive code?

Thanks

```
export class Select2Directive  {
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private model: NgModel) {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).select2({
        width: '100%',
        theme: "bootstrap",
        placeholder: "SELECT",
        allowClear: true
    });

    var model = this.model;
    $(this.el.nativeElement).on('select2:select select2:unselecting', function (e: any) {

        let value = (e.type == 'select2:unselecting') ? "" : e.currentTarget.value;
        model.viewToModelUpdate(value);

    });


}
```

}

Comment: Please show the whole relevant code in order to understand your issue

Comment: Please share your directive

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer

Instead of model.viewToModelUpdate(value) need write model.reset(value)